# `path.basename` like function, but to get the root of a path

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

`os.path` has the `basename` function that returns the last folder/file of the given path, i wonder if there is a easy way to get the root of a path (and why there's not a function to it in the `os.path` module)

```
>>> from os import path
>>> path.basename('./a/b/c')
'c'
>>> """ what if we could do like so:
>>> path.rootname('./a/b/c')
>>> './a'
>>> """
```

The first thing i though is to make a recursion of `path.dirname` in the destination till it gets to the root folder but i can't think a optimal way to do so, tried to play around with `.split` str method but also couldn't implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `pathlib` is here for the rescue?

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path("./foo/bar/baz.qwurx")
print(p.parents[len(p.parents)-1])
print(p.parents[len(p.parents)-2])
print(p.parents[len(p.parents)-3])
```

yields

```
.
foo
foo/bar
```

note that `./foo` and `foo` are equal.

Comment: yes baby this is it

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem (someone pls submit a PEP about this function)

```
from os import path
from pathlib import Path

def rootname(dest: str):
    """
    Will return the root of a path.
    """
    p = Path(dest)

    return path.join(
        p.parents[len(p.parents) - 1],
        p.parents[len(p.parents) - 2]
    )
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what is the use of this function, but it can be written more succinctly like this: `return path.join(*Path(dest).parents[-1:-3:-1])`